# Importing production database to another server throws error

Tags: mysql, database, import

I have a production database of 2.5 GB which I exported using `mysqldump`.
I tried to import that `.dump` file in another server by running

> mysql -uroot moodle < moodle.dump --verbose

it runs for few seconds and get stuck. When I checked  `mysql_error.log`

```
2018-06-27 11:14:36 5000 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.column_stats: expected column 'max_value' at position 4 to have type varbinary(255), found type varchar(255).
2018-06-27 11:18:33 5124 [Warning] InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
--Thread 5200 has waited at ibuf0ibuf.cc line 4403 for 241.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 00C3C3F0, Mutex IBUF created ibuf0ibuf.cc:516, lock var 2

2018-06-27 11:18:33 5124 [Warning] InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
--Thread 4212 has waited at ibuf0ibuf.cc line 4403 for 241.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 00C3C3F0, Mutex IBUF created ibuf0ibuf.cc:516, lock var 2

2018-06-27 11:18:33 5124 [Warning] InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
--Thread 3956 has waited at btr0pcur.cc line 444 for 241.00 seconds the semaphore:
X-lock on RW-latch at 04844024 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1478
a writer (thread id 4440) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file not yet reserved line 0
Last time write locked in file btr0cur.cc line 293
2018-06-27 11:18:33 5124 [Warning] InnoDB: A long semaphore wait:
--Thread 4440 has waited at buf0buf.cc line 4145 for 241.00 seconds the semaphore:
S-lock on RW-latch at 0483BA74 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1478
a writer (thread id 0) has reserved it in mode  exclusive
number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0
Last time read locked in file dict0stats.cc line 1556
Last time write locked in file buf0buf.cc line 5349
2018-06-27 11:18:33 5124 [Note] InnoDB: A semaphore wait:
--Thread 5200 has waited at ibuf0ibuf.cc line 4403 for 241.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 00C3C3F0, Mutex IBUF created ibuf0ibuf.cc:516, lock var 2
```

In production database works fine, what will be the problem?
I am using `10.2.8-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution` xampp 3.2.2 in windows server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Try running the mysql_upgrade_service command

```
mysql_upgrade_service --service=MySQL
```

See for more details https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/

Comment: how should i run this command? just copy and paste in command prompt? 
It throws me an error `Phase 1/8: Changing service configuration  ,
FATAL ERROR: OpenService failed with 1060`

Comment: Thats quite a different error, can you provide more details on what you are running on the server? virtualbox, wamp?

Comment: I am using xampp in virtual server, I installed wamp before but it is already uninstalled..

Comment: Afraid it's a xampp / wamp based issue. I have no knowledge on how to resolve that. Maybe a seperate question?